# On Linux/Mac/Windows, is it possible to access the TCP timestamp and/or RTT in user space of a connected TCP socket?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

On Linux/Mac/Windows, is it possible to access the TCP timestamp and/or RTT in user space of a connected TCP socket? I'm referring to the TCP timestamp and associated RTT calculation enabled by [RFC 1323](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1323). Obviously, I could utilize a raw socket, but the socket would neither be connected or capable of sending TCP packets on Windows (post XP Update 3, I believe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows (EstatsType = TcpConnectionEstatsFineRtt):
[GetPerTcp6ConnectionEStats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb485735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[GetPerTcpConnectionEStats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb485738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

On Linux (tcp_info.tcpi_rtt):
[Measuring TCP Congestion Windows (getsockopt)](http://linuxgazette.net/136/pfeiffer.html)

On Mac (xtcpcb64.t_srtt):
[sysctl TCPCTL_PCBLIST to acquire the xtcpcb64 struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31301406/3638462)

Comment: `GetPerTcpConnectionEStats` on Windows is possible but requires Administator access to enable the Extended Statistics in the first place, unlike Linux and OSX, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I want to append more information.

For iOS/MacOSX, I found another method which is very similar with `Linux tcp_info`. It's `struct tcp_connection_info`. You can find it in the `usr/include/netinet/tcp.h` of the iOS/MacOSX xcode sdk. You can use it as the following:

```
int length = sizeof(struct tcp_connection_info);  
getsockopt(socket_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_CONNECTION_INFO, (void *)info, (socklen_t *)&length);
```

I tested it on iOS 10.2.